# I need to install one Magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2, theme, installation

I found one [free theme](https://github.com/czone-tech/magento2-theme-fresh) and I want to install it on my server, I follow this steps but the theme is not available in the Magento admin Content > Design > Configuration.

```
1. Create a folder {Magento root}/app/design/frontend/CzoneTech
2. Extract the contents of the zipped folder inside it.
```

So now my directory structure is look like:

[image]

what I need to do next? or what is wrong?

I run php bin/magento s:s:d and this is the output of the command:

```
 [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "de
  veloper" modes.
  In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed autom
  atically on demand.
  If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: 'bin/magento set
  up:static-content:deploy -f'
```

And for php bin/magento setup:upgrade the output is:

```
Nothing to import.
Please re-run Magento compile command. Use the command "setup:di:compile"
```

Comment: Did you execut `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` ? and `php bin/magento s:s:d` ?

Comment: no, what do this command: php bin/magento s:s:d

Comment: short version of `static-content:deploy`

Comment: please take a look I edit my post and I put there the output of the commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded theme and configured and it is working fine , I think you put theme content in wrong directory. Just copy downloaded theme content into

`app/design/frontend/CzoneTech/Fresh`

and execute below commands,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**EDIT**

If you want to remove theme then you can execute below command,

```
php bin/magento theme:uninstall
```

You can execute this command If you Installed the theme by composer, otherwise you need to remove theme component manually.

Comment: can you tell me please one thing? what command I need to add to remove the theme?

Comment: For the Install theme you do not need to do anything. and for remove please see my edit @Robert

Answer (score 0):

You need to create folder under *CzoneTech* directory and extract all files there.

```
app/design/frontend/CzoneTech/ThemeName/
```

Replace *ThemeName* to your theme name.

Comment: and there I need to put the content of the arhive?

Comment: Yes, all right.